# How to Trim and Update Attribute values for NiFi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi, processors

I want to trim all of the whitespace leading and/or tailing the subject.

NiFi Processors being used:

1. Get File
2. Extract Text
3. Update Attribute --The issue lies here
4. AttributestoJSON
5. ConvertJSONtoSQL
6. PutSQL
7. PutFile

Mock Email:

*****Body of Email fake data obviously*****

Student: Troy Bolton

Classification: Junior

ID: 880647

DOB: 8/26/1995

SSN: 218-54-6321

School: Harvard

Note: Apartment, No Roommate

****End Body of Email****

When I use the Regex function trim() for NiFi it does not trim the leading or tailing whitespace from its subject.

Question: Using the above, how would I correctly achieve this using the UpdateAttribute processor??

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: What goes on within the first two processors. How do you extract the lines, what separator do you use, how do you get the attributes ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the UpdateAttribute processor, if the property name is Student but the property name in the ExtractText is Student-1 and the attribute you are looking for is Student then you would

```
${Student-1:substringAfter('Student: '):trim()}
```